# How to add Nunit 3 testcontext to Specflow scenario

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit, specflow, gherkin

I would like to implement Nunit testcontext option in to my specflow ScenarioContext. I tried adding this line manually in the RandomName.Feature.cs file's ScenarioSetup method

```
testRunner.ScenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<NUnit.Framework.TestContext>(TestContext);

testRunner.ScenarioContext.Add("TestContext", TestContext);
```

But the name test context does not exist in the current context.  Any pointers on how to make use of the Nunit test context in specflow please

Comment: Why are you adding ...<NUnit.Framework.TestContext>(TestContext) nut not TestContext.CurrentContext ?

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out @unickq That worked without any issues.

Comment: Also, should this be always added under each auto generated feature file.cs or is it possible to make it to work by having along with custom created BeforeScenario method in hook file. My intention here is to make this step generic so that I dont end up adding it manually for each feature file. Thanks again for the previous response. :)

Comment: you're welcome. I'll post solution as an answer - so everyone who faces with it will find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestContext.**CurrentContext** is required

```
testRunner.ScenarioContext.ScenarioContainer
.RegisterInstanceAs<NUnit.Framework.TestContext>(TestContext.CurrentContext);
```